# Jquery css(width, 0) not working if the element is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a quick [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qUWnF/) showing it not working.

The problem I have is with the slide up. I want it to work so that it only sets the width to 0 after the slideup has finished. The obvious callback function does not seem to be getting called after the slideup has finished.

I would like it to work like this:

1. Shows the red box by sliding down and increasing the width together.
2. Click again and the box slides up then sets the width the 0. So that if the user clicks the button again the first animation would appear the same.

   var $foo = $("#elm");

   ```
   $("#btn").toggle(function() {
       showDropDown();
   }, function() {
       hideDropDown();
   });

   function showDropDown(){
       $foo.slideDown({duration:500, queue:false}).animate({"width": 400}, 250);
   }

   function hideDropDown(){
       $foo.slideUp({duration:800, queue:false},function(){
           $foo.css({"width": 0});
       });            
   }
   ```

UPDATE:
The strange thing is that if I add a alert() into the callback function for slidedown it never gets called.

Comment: The animation appears the same when I click multiple times? I'm on Chrome17/WindowsServer

Comment: slideUp will hide the thing by sliding it up then what is the use of making its width to 0?

Comment: Because of the first animation with slidedown and width together. The second time this function is called the width is already set inline.

Comment: Here's a dirty way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/qUWnF/12/

Comment: Or you could do it like this, though I needed to take out `queue:false` http://jsfiddle.net/qUWnF/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Sorry for the first answer, didn't pay attention.

The problem is that the callback is not executed, because you don't give the parameters according to the [API](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), and the callback is not "wired" in.

Instead, you can use the `promise().done(...)` combination to achieve the objective you wanted.

So, you should modify your `hideDropDown` method as follows:

```
function hideDropDown(){
    $foo.slideUp({duration:800, queue:false}).promise().done(function(){
        $foo.css("width", "0px");
    });            
}
```

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/promise/):

"The .promise() method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have ended."

Comment: The OP is using display:none;

Comment: Corrected answer. Sorry for not reading the question thoroughly.

Comment: Perfect thanks. The promise feature looks cool. I will have a good read of this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to use animate to reset width to 0 like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sinsedrix/reG5H/11/):

```
var $foo = $("#elm");

$("#btn").toggle(function() {
    showDropDown();
}, function() {
    hideDropDown();
});

function showDropDown(){
    $foo.slideDown({duration:500, queue:false}).animate({"width": 400}, 250);
}

function hideDropDown(){
    $foo.slideUp({duration:800, queue:false}).animate({"width": 0}, 1);
}
```

or set width to 0 like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sinsedrix/reG5H/10/):

```
function hideDropDown(){
    $foo.slideUp({duration:800, queue:false}).width(0);
}
```

Comment: Both your examples slide down OK but the slide up just instantly hides because of the width.

Comment: I want the slide up to finish then set the width to 0

Comment: `slideUp`/`slideDown` won't animate width by default. May be you sould use a custom animate function. See http://jsfiddle.net/sinsedrix/reG5H/12/

Answer (score 0):

Why not chain .animate() after .slideUp()?

```
$foo.slideUp({duration: 800, queue: false}).animate({"width": 0}, 800);
```

Comment: Because I want the slide up to finish (completely hidden) then set the width to 0